# Bijection between sets of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\left ( B \times C \right )^A=\{f \in \mathcal{P} \left ( \left ( B \times C \right) \times A \right) \big | f \hspace{2mm} \text{is a function and} \hspace{2mm} \text{dom}(f)=B \times C  \}$

Let $B^A = \{ f \in \mathcal{P} \left ( B \times A \right) \big | f \hspace{2mm} \text{is a function} \hspace{2mm} \text{dom}(f)=B \}$

Let $C^A = \{ f \in \mathcal{P} \left ( C \times A \right) \big | f \hspace{2mm} \text{is a function} \hspace{2mm} \text{dom}(f)=C \}$

Prove $\left ( B \times C \right) ^A \equiv_C B^A \times C^A $

I know I need to find a bijection but have no real idea how to start. Any hints as to where to begin are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you mistaked [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (i.e. "inputs") with [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) (i.e. "outputs"). Notation $A^B$ in set theory (or sometimes written $^B\!\!A$ to avoid exactly such mistakes) denotes the set of functions $B \to A$, i.e. $$ f \in A^B \iff \mathrm{dom}(f) = B \land \mathrm{cod}(f) = A.$$

As to your question, the general idea is that $B\times C$ can be understood as a pair, i.e. there are two projections $\pi_B : B\times C \to B$ and $\pi_C : B \times C \to C$ that would extract the elements of the pair. Then, given function $f : A \to B \times C$, you can ignore one element of a pair, for example $(\pi_C \circ f) \in C^A$. Having such two functions (one for $B$ and one for $C$) you can compose it again, after calculating the result of $f$.

If you still have problems starting, I can provide you with an example of bijection between $C^{A\times B}$ and $(C^B)^A$ which is known commonly as [currying and uncurrying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Consider

$$\mathrm{curry}(f) = x \mapsto y \mapsto f(x,y),$$
or in different notation
$$\mathrm{curry}(f)(x)(y) = f(x,y).$$

Then, its inverse is
$$\mathrm{uncurry}(f) = (x,y) \mapsto f(x)(y),$$
or written in the alternate way,
$$\mathrm{uncurry}(f)(x,y) = f(x)(y).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$